# Get the Two Select Value in one Button Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the two values in one click of a button, so when they click search now  a modal will appear, this is the current code  I have . But when I tried to use this code only one value appears

```
<select id="search" class="modal-trigger" name="search" data-modal="modal-name">
    <option selected="selected" value="select">Select an Event</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
</select>

<select id="searchcity" class="modal-trigger" name="searchcity" data-modal="modal-name">
    <option selected="selected" value="select">Search a City</option>
    <option value="City1">City1</option>
    <option value="City2">City2</option>
    <option value="City3">City3</option>
    <option value="City4">City4</option>
    <option value="City5">City5</option>
</select>
<button id="searchnow">Search</button> 
      $("#searchnow").click(function () {

    var selectedCity = $("#searchcity").val();
    var selectedEvent = $("#search").val();

    console.log(selectedCity)
    console.log(selectedCity)
    $.getJSON('events.json', 
         function (data) {
        render(selectedCity, data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually doing all things perfect.
The only problem I can find is you are doing the console.log same variable

```
 console.log(selectedCity)
    console.log(selectedCity)
```

Change it to

```
console.log(selectedCity)
    console.log(selectedEvent )
```

```js
 $("#searchnow").click(function () {

    var selectedCity = $("#searchcity").val();
    var selectedEvent = $("#search").val();

    console.log(selectedCity)
    console.log(selectedEvent)
    $.getJSON('events.json', 
         function (data) {
        render(selectedCity, data);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="search" class="modal-trigger" name="search" data-modal="modal-name">
    <option selected="selected" value="select">Select an Event</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="all">All</option>
    </select></p>

<select id="searchcity" class="modal-trigger" name="searchcity" data-modal="modal-name">
<option selected="selected" value="select">Search a City</option>
<option value="City1">City1</option>
<option value="City2">City2</option>
<option value="City3">City3</option>
<option value="City4">City4</option>
<option value="City5">City5</option>
</select>
<button id="searchnow">Search</button>
```